# Removing characters from data extension field via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, substring

A field used in a sendable data extension contains a value that I'm trying to remove the beginning characters from then add the remaining characters to the end of a different URL.

Example:
**Data Extension Value** (everything after the '/' is unique to each record): 'www.mywebsite.com/bill'
**Target URL**: 'www.differentwebsite.com'
**Desired Outcome**: www.differentwebsite.com/bill

I believe I could accomplish this with the substring and concat function, but can't seem to figure out the proper formatting as I receive an error stating:

> The function call uses an unrecognized function name.
>    Function Name: ‘AttributeValue
>    Function Call: ‘AttributeValue("websiteURL")*

Here's what I tried so far:

```
%%[

Set @pws = Substring(‘AttributeValue("websiteUrl")’,21)
Set @link1 = Concat('http://differentwebsite.com', @pws)
]%%
```

With the asset linked to: `%%=Redirect(@link1)=%%`

Comment: Looks like you have come curly-apostrophes in there.

Comment: Also, it needs to start from 18 I think, not 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up modifying to the following to get the desired result:

%%[

Set @pws = Substring(AttributeValue("websiteUrl"),21)
Set @link1 = Concat('http://differentwebsite.com', @pws)
]%%

Note for my specific case '21' was the correct number of characters to cut off at, in the example scenario I posted it should be '18' as Selim mentioned.